# Network error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at new ApolloError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, graphql, apollo

[image]

```
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:3090/'
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
})

client.query({
  query: gql`
    query users {
        email
    }
  `,
})
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

This query gives an error when fetching from client-side code but when i execute this query in browser on http://localhost:3090/graphql it fetches data correctly

Comment: Open network tab in developers console and tell us what `ApolloError` is.

Comment: @kiarashws added a screenshot for the request

Comment: as you can see `Status Code` is 404(not found), which means given url is incorrect.

Comment: Looks like your request is not answered with a JSON object but an HTML page `<HTML>...`. Typically the case for unhandled errors, where you are served a default error page. Because you're connecting to the root URL, my guess is a 404?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The graphql endpoint you are posting your queries to is missing the `/graphql`. So your server probably returns an html document containing the 404 error message that starts with `<` from `<html...`. Apollo tries to parse that as the query result and fails to do so.

Check that `httpLink` is actually `localhost:3090/graphql`.

Also the syntax of a query is either:

```
{
    users {
        email
    }
}
```

or if you want to name the query:

```
query Users {
    users {
        email
    }
}
```

Comment: @MukeshKumar please add the full error message to your question.

Comment: after adding /graphql ..?

Comment: @MukeshKumar Yes. I can't tell you why it fails without the message.

Comment: POST http://localhost:3090/graphql 400 (Bad Request)    
index.js:1452 Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400
    at new ApolloError (ApolloError.js:58)
    at QueryManager.js:522
    at QueryManager.js:982
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at QueryManager.js:981
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at QueryManager.broadcastQueries (QueryManager.js:977)
    at QueryManager.js:477

Comment: @MukeshKumar I'm affraid that does not contain any helpful information. But I think that the syntax of your query is incorrect too. It must be just ``gql`{ users { email } }``  or ``qgl`query Users { users { email } }` ``.

Comment: Looks like a network issue. Check where your backend is serving from. I made the same mistake

Answer (score 1):

For posterity in case someone finds this in the future, another reason you might get this error is if your API is returning something other than JSON.
https://medium.com/programmers-developers/one-simple-apollo-client-debugging-tip-youll-like-7877a97b9c16

I ran into this issue because the content type that was being returned from my API was `text/plain` rather than `application/json`. Apollo lets you specify a different body serializer in this case.
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/rest/

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you do not define the path correctly in the queries files. This is a typechecking error when passing arguments

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was being thrown due to a trailing slash I had after the API URL. A possible fix would be checking your API URL properly and ensuring it is referencing the correct URL.

In my case, I only had to take out the trailing slash `/` after the URL.

Answer (score 0):

As @Trixn posted: "So your server probably returns an html document containing the 404 error message that starts with < from <html.... Apollo tries to parse that as the query result and fails to do so."

In my case, I did not put "http://" in the beginning of my URL, and this returned a HTML web page with an error message.

Also check that usually, you should use "https://"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have configured the uri for httpLink and wsLink same.
I have seen this error when I had different uris as below.

httpLink had uri : "http://localhost:4000"
wsLink had uri: "ws://localhost:4000/graphql"

setting httpLink's uri to http://localhost:4000/graphql helped resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I recieved the same error, when I switched from a `create-react-app` to a next JS app pointing to port **3000**.The react app had some values saved to local storage (tokens). In my case all I had to do, was to clear the local storage for `localhost:3000`, and I got rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a typo in my graphql endpoint url. I had added a few characters to the end by accident. I think it would be good practice to add a catch rule for this situation so it does not break the site, just does not show the content and posts error to console log.